# How can I view stdout/stderr of a startup application?

Tags: log, startup-applications, stdout

Some of the commands that I have in Startup Applications do not start properly when I login. (In particular I am having trouble with gtk-redshift.)  In order to debug, I would like to be able to view stdout/stderr.  I haven't found a log file for Startup Applications.  I have tried redirecting to a file using ">> log.txt" with no success.

How can I see stdout/stderr for a Startup Application?  Better yet, is there a log file for Startup Applications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best thing to do would either put the bash command further below in startup or put it in a bash script and select that in your startup applications. I have added the `-v` option so the application records all its actions with the greatest of detail; some applications have other verbosity settings and even various levels that you can specify.

The `&>` redirection used is the same as `2>&1` in that it redirects all of the program's output (`stderr, stdout`) to the specified file, i.e. `&>/home/mike/redshift.log`.

Here is the command that could be used to set up logging, and it could be used for other programs, if modified appropriately.

```
bash -c "setsid /usr/bin/gtk-redshift -v -l 40.77:-73.9 -t 6500:5500 &>/home/mike/redshift.log"
```

These are just sample test settings, substitute these values for your own; you may want to put the command, modified appropriately in a bash wrapper for your startup entry as the above command-line is quite long.

An excerpt from the log created at `/home/mike/redshift.log`:

```
Gamma ramp size too small: 0
Failed to start adjustment method randr.
Trying next method...
Location: 40.770000, -73.900002
Brightness: 1.00
Gamma: 1.000, 1.000, 1.000
Using method `vidmode'.
```

The log continues and should give you the information you need. Some programs such as `vlc` do have options that you can set up so their logging can be sent to syslog, but I prefer that each program has its own separate log.

Comment: What if a built-in program print an error? For example X-Window?

Answer (score -1):

Please check `/var/log/syslog`. Its common for all the applications.

Comment: I guess I should have been more explicit.  I've checked /var/log/syslog, already.  The startup applications in question do not make log entries to syslog.  I also see no logs from any kind of Startup Application script/wrapper.

Comment: Would you mind disclosing the application names?

Comment: As stated in the question, the main culprit is gtk-redshift.  Also troublesome is google-musicmanager.